# Vertically align stubborn paragraphs

Tags: html, alignment, jsfiddle

I have been trying to get an 'About Us' section to vertically align to the paragraph below it.  For some reason, when I try to resize the viewing area or look at it from a smaller screen, About and Us are on two different lines, and if you keep making the area smaller 'About Us' will drop down below and to the left of the entire paragraph.

My first question that I was pondering is how do I make it so the 'About Us' text stays on one line, rather than folding in to two or more lines.  My second would be how can I make this scalable without dropping the 'about us' text below the paragraph?

Attached is my code in JSFiddle.

Thanks guys!!

http://jsfiddle.net/2L9qU/

Here is the troubling html:

```
                <div class="mainContentContainer">
                <div class="mainContent1">
                        <h1>
                ABOUT US
            </h1>

                </div></div>
```

Here is the accompanying CSS:

```
.mainContentContainer {
    width: 85%
}
.mainContent1 h1 {
    font-family:verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#00245D;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 10%;
}
.mainContent1 {
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 100px;
    width: 35%;
}
.mainContent2 {
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: -6%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You'll hate this idea, but you can solve the problem immediately by just putting the thing into a table.

Comment: You're right, I hate that idea :P
I'd much rather keep things scaleable.

Comment: Regarding preventing the `<h1>` from breaking to two lines, could you add `.mainContent1 h1 {white-space:nowrap;}` to your CSS?

Comment: For future reference, jsfiddle will wrap anything in the HTML box with a doctype and `<html>`/`<body>` tags (and `<head>`, but that's not wrapping your content), so you only need to put `<body>` content into the HTML box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is rather messy, so I've tried a simpler approach with a "cleaned up" markup (see http://jsfiddle.net/danielecocca/9eJnt/).

- HTML

  ```
  <div class="table">
      <div class="table-row">
          <ul class="table-cell">
              <!-- left side pane contents here -->
          </ul>
          <div class="table-cell">
              <!-- right side pane contents here -->
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  ```
- CSS

  ```
  .table {
      display: table;
  }

  .table-row {
      display: table-row;
  }

  .table-cell {
      display: table-cell;
  }
  ```

This uses a couple of container `div` elements, one styled as `display: table` and the other as `display: table-row`, and a left side and right side pane style as `display: table-cell`. With a little bit of tweaking, it should definitely match your needs (no real `table` element used, displayed as a table, resizes just fine).

To avoid breaking up on multiple lines, I second what suggested by Serlite: you can use `white-space: nowrap`, which treats spaces as if they were non-breaking space entities (`&nbsp;`).

Comment: Ah, much better.  Include the contents of the Fiddle in your answer directly, however; Fiddle links can go down, rendering your answer useless.

Comment: I used a Fiddle just so he could have a way to watch the "live" result, but you're right, I'm gonna embed some code in the response.

Comment: After a bit of 'fiddling' I finally got this to work more or less correctly!
Thank you so much for your help!!